# IntelliJ: project not generated with android tool - permission denied

Tags: android, linux, intellij-idea

I'm at a bit of a loss with this one, I'm sure it's a pretty simple problem really.

[image: Permission denied error]

It has located the SDK and I have already installed the required build tools etc. For some reason it doesn't have permission to access the files.

I'm using ubuntu and the SDK is installed in /usr/local/android/android-sdk-linux/ . Is this as simple a problem as me placing the SDK in a bad location?

EDIT: I have fixed the issue by using the following in the command line:

```
chmod a+x .../tools/android
```

However, I'd like to know if I've removed all issues I might face in the future, and how I should actually correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this:

I have fixed the issue by using the following in the command line:

chmod a+x .../tools/android

Thus allowing access to the android function in the tools directory. Everything seems to be working fine now.